# Replicating C# SHA256 hash in PHP

Tags: c#, php, hash

I am trying to access an API which requires header authorization in PHP. This authorization uses in part a SHA256 hash with a key. The API creators have supplied me with an .exe written in C# to create this hash. However, now it is not feasible to use the .exe and I would like to do it in PHP.

Here is the correct C# code that makes the hash.

```
var url = "[url]";

var userId = "apiuser";

var timestamp = "Fri, 14 Jul 2017 00:28:07 GMT"; // DateTime.UtcNow;

var keyString = "dGVzdA==";

var hashData = String.Format("GET\n{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n", url, userId, timestamp); //.ToString("r"));

var key = Convert.FromBase64String(keyString);
string hashString;

using (var hmac = new HMACSHA256(key))
{
    var hash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hashData));
    hashString = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
}
Console.WriteLine(hashString);
```

C# Hash: CfS6zNR3pTP0kJIA0RJ7LUwQXjONroVIg65bDvuefH8=

Here is my attempt to replicate it in PHP

```
$key = "dGVzdA==";
$user = "apiuser";
$url = "[url]";

$timestamp = "Fri, 14 Jul 2017 00:28:07 GMT"; // date("D, d M Y H:i:s e");

$hashdata = 'GET\n' . $url . '\n' . $user . '\n' . $timestamp;

$generatedhash = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $hashdata, base64_decode($key), true));

print_r($generatedhash);
```

PHP Hash: 6cI0NV6AKYILTyYHs+hyA0+Q4iRfMw+H2FGsp7uKOFM=

I have attempted lots of different approaches to the PHP generated hash and none have been the same. Also I am not sure if the PHP date is the same as the C# date but that can wait. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Put all your \n's inside double quotes, try that for the php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare this

```
var hashData = String.Format("GET\n{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n", url, userId, timestamp);
```

To this

```
$hashdata = 'GET\n' . $url . '\n' . $user . '\n' . $timestamp;
```

You're missing the ending '\n' and as @ Fred-ii- points out PHP will only treat \n as a character escape inside "" not '':

```
$hashdata = "GET\n" . $url . "\n" . $user . "\n" . $timestamp . "\n" ;
```

Or just this since PHP evaluates variables inside "":

```
$hashdata = "GET\n$url\n$user\n$timestamp\n" ;
```

**Single vs. double quotes in PHP:**

- A string in single quotes 'hello $person\r\n' is taken exactly as written.  Instead of the \r\n being a carriage return - line feed pair it is the 4 characters '\' 'r' '\' '\n' and $person appears **as** "$person".
- A string in double quotes "hello $person\r\n" is processed in 2 ways: 1. any $name is treated as a variable and is replaced by that variable's value (empty string if the variable does not exist).  2.  Character escapes like \r \n and \ work like in other languages.

Comment: Thanks for the response, can't believe I missed that "\n". I did add that on but it is still different when I tested again. The "true" parameter in hash_hmac() should be the same as encoding utf8? Anyway I did test with utf8_encode($hashdata) but it didn't change the result.

Comment: \n need to be inside of double quotes I do believe in the php

Comment: Good catch @Fred-ii-

Comment: Let's see what the OP will say now. Hopefully it will be "Eureka!"

Comment: Thank you guys that did work :) Can you explain to me why that was needed?

Comment: See edit, "x" and 'x' behave differently in PHP, neither one quite matches C++ or C#.

Comment: I know I am not supposed to just say thanks here but thanks @DaveS :)